# Why are files being removed from /tmp?

Tags: centos, unix, tmp, tmpwatch

I use centOS5, 
but these files of /tmp is deleted automatically when time passes.
 What kind of structure will this kill him in? 
In addition, How  to stop this?

Comment: The whole point of /tmp is for files to be there temporarily.  Otherwise it will fill up!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have `tmpwatch` installed

```
# rpm -qa | grep tmpwatch
tmpwatch-2.9.7-1.1.el5.2
```

Then that will be clearing your `/tmp` regularly (it *is* called tmp for a reason)

`tmpwatch` is run from cron on a daily basis, check out `/etc/cron.daily/tmpwatch`

Answer (score 3):

The best thing to do is ask yourself why you are storing long-lived files in /tmp in the first place.  And then change the way you work so that it doesn't happen.

/tmp (tmp is short for temporary) is designed for short-lived (scratch) files which are created, used and deleted in a short period of time.  It can also hold some sockets which are re-created every boot (X11 does this).  I think most backup software will skip /tmp by default, too.

If you have an application that insists on keeping anything other than scratch files in /tmp, file a bug report.

Comment: This reminds me of the Windows user who was storing files he wanted to keep in his recycle bin (true story)!

Comment: Yes, I heard that story.  I also remember reading a forum thread where someone kept his emails in his mail client's trash folder.